# how to show a leave info that starts from the end of month and ends with the first of month?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have a form where a user can see how many leave of him has been approved. but the problem start when the user apply for leave selecting the date that start with the end date of the month and ends with the starting of the month.

this is the query

```
SELECT l.applicationID
     , l.empID
     , e.name
     , l.typeID
     , t.title
     , t.allowed_leave
     , l.start_date
     , l.end_date
     , l.comment
     , l.status 
  FROM leave_application l 
  JOIN employee e
    ON e.empID = l.empID 
  JOIN leave_type t
    ON t.typeID = l.typeID 
 where l.empID = $employee_id 
   AND status = 'approved' 
   AND start_date LIKE '$start_date%'
```

Now when the user tries to select that starting month that is showed in the list but when he select the end date , that is not being showed as the query for end date is not defined.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should avoid concatenation on your SQL string and use prepared statement instead to prevent SQL injection. Then you can use SQL date functions to test the year and month like this;

```
// getting the input from the request
$inputDate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'startDate');
// splitting the string into an array
$dateParts = explode('-', $inputDate);

$sql = 'SELECT .. FROM yourtable WHERE some tests'

// adding the variable part of the query where clause
// the question marks will be replaced by true values 
// when you will execute the query
if (count($dateParts) >= 2){
  $sql .= ' AND YEAR(startDate)=? AND MONTH(startDate)= ?'
} 
if (count($dateParts) == 3){
  $sql .= ' AND DAY(startDate)=?'
}

// Preparing and executing the query
$dbConnection = new PDO(...);
$statement = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
// executing the query passing the values as an array
$statement->execute($dateParts);
```

Hope it would helps cheers